# How do I update the database using php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here is my first UPDATE query in which i am updating the date, but it is not happening. I made sure that the query is not successful by checking the no of updated rows.

```
    $ddline = $_POST['deadline_sem'];
    $ex=explode('T', $ddline);
    $date="$ex[0] $ex[1]";
    $deadline=date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($date));
    echo $deadline;
    $qry1="UPDATE admin SET RegDeadline='$deadline' where username='root'";
    if(mysql_affected_rows()>=0)
        echo "Success";
    else
        echo "Unsuccesull";
```

Comment: Which DB you r using...

Comment: I think you are missing the line to execute the '$qry1",
mysql_query($qry1) before ''mysql_affected_rows()"

Answer (score 1):

Possible way why your code is not working

1) No database connection code.

2) Missing execute statement `mysql_query($qry1);`

Your code is open for sql injection

Use `mysql_real_escape_string()` before update into database.

```
$deadline=mysql_real_escape_string($deadline);
$qry1="UPDATE admin SET RegDeadline='$deadline' where username='root'";
mysql_query($qry1);// execute statement
if(mysql_affected_rows()>=0)
       echo "Success";
else
     echo "Unsuccesull";
```

> Note:-
>   mysql is deprecated instead use PDO or mysqli